# Xamarin : System.Net.ProtocolViolationException

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Currently, I had write Photo Application ,
When I take the Photo ,when Upload the Photo to Server, it display this Error.

**System.Net.ProtocolViolationException: The number of bytes to be written is greater than the specified ContentLength.**

[Error in Protocol](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m8wYY.png)

Comment: PLEASE take the time to read the posting guidelines, especially http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.  Posting screenshots of code/errors is highly discouraged.  You seem to repeatedly do this on every post, even though multiple people have tried to help you refine your Questions to abide by the SO guidelines.

Comment: I think that error message says it all. Make sure your ContentLength header is the same as the number of bytes in your image.